# Insert Data into varchar from char

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to insert a value into varchar column1 in Table 1 from char column2 in Table 2. What is the sql query I can use? Thanks.

I got an error using this query:

```
insert into Table1 (Column1 ,Column2)
select Table2.Column1, Table2.Column2
from Table2.
```

> String or binary data would be truncated.

Comment: What is the maximum length for each column?

Comment: char(18) and varchar(13)

Comment: Then it will fail if you have `char` data longer than 13 characters.

Answer (score 2):

A `char` column always consumes all of the space available. If the data is shorter than the length specified, it will be padded with spaces.

If you're sure that all of the data is actually short enough to fit into the new, smaller, column, then use [`RTRIM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178660.aspx) to remove the unwanted padding:

```
insert into Table1 (Column1 ,Column2)
select RTRIM(Table2.Column1), RTRIM(Table2.Column2)
from Table2
```

(Not sure which of the columns actually needs the `RTRIM` because your narrative talks of inserting `Column2` from `Table2` into `Column1` of `Table1`, but that's not what this query does)